# Mongoose search for element in utmost sub array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

My schema is as follows

```
{
  product:[{
    structure :[{
      version:[{
        type:[{
          values:[{}]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Need to search fields in values array.
Actually I need to update the fields in values array. I'm unable to write query to get sub array values. How can I do that.  Kindly let me know, as soon as possible.

Comment: Maybe, $in operator might help you a little. Diving into nesting properties. But this structure is definitely not the best approach. You know about 16MB, right?

Comment: yes, There is no much content.. so, going with the above approach.. how $in operator helpful.. Could you let me know the process.

Comment: Yes, not $in... try to look into $where. Most probably writing a custom function is the only way here...

Comment: Daily sermon again. Do not nest arrays. Whatever perceived advantage you think this has does not actually exist. Right away I see the names of each array in fact should be instead the "properties" listed on all of you "innermost" entries. There are huge limitations here and no advantages. Making this **one** single array and defining the properties on each member will make every task easy. See the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) documentation.

Comment: @NeilLunn , If I remove all arrays and make only one array then....for suppose if I have a property in version.. that should be replicate in all Values array data. like that in all arrays data replication will happen. so, If I compare size of above format and the format of single array.. which is best.

Comment: Yes you replicate the values. This is not a "denormalization" exercise, and if you do not understand that then please give up and go and use a relational database instead. You need to work with "the way things actually work" as opposed to "how **you** think they should work". Take my word for it that I am speaking from a position of having more experience in this than you do. What you think is the right thing to do is wrong. Do like we are ( and the documentation is as well ) telling you to do and "flatten" the data to a single array. Problem solved. Out.

Comment: ya understood. I will flatten the data.. my question is.. Replication of data will exists in rows right. so, is that fine or not... I'm new to this.. So, just confirming once

Answer (score 0):

You can use this types of query:

```
// match a one name
db.getCollection('test').find({"product.structure.version.type.values.name":'test'})
// match some value from an array
db.getCollection('test').find({"product.structure.version.type.values.name": {$in: [1, 'test']}})
```

Last query will find 3 items in the next collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595b9e17c482ca1b99db23a6"),
    "product" : [ 
        {
            "structure" : [ 
                {
                    "version" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : [ 
                                {
                                    "values" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "name" : 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595b9e68f9f2fe8d79ca4c82"),
    "product" : [ 
        {
            "structure" : [ 
                {
                    "version" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : [ 
                                {
                                    "values" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "name" : 3
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "name" : 4
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "name" : 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595b9e71f9f2fe8d79ca4c84"),
    "product" : [ 
        {
            "structure" : [ 
                {
                    "version" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : [ 
                                {
                                    "values" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "name" : 5
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595ba08af9f2fe8d79ca4cd9"),
    "product" : [ 
        {
            "structure" : [ 
                {
                    "version" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : [ 
                                {
                                    "values" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "name" : 6
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595ba0f1f9f2fe8d79ca4d00"),
    "product" : [ 
        {
            "structure" : [ 
                {
                    "version" : [ 
                        {
                            "type" : [ 
                                {
                                    "values" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "name" : "test"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
To do an update query, you need to do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"product.structure.version.type.values.name": {$in: [1, 'test']}}, {$set: {"product.$.testProp": 'some test string'}}, {multi: true})
```

Comment: what is the meaning of  {$in: [1, 'test']} in find operation.

Comment: It's looking for `name` field match some element from the array `[1, 'test']`.
Please see documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: I did the same way, what you suggested in find operation for array.. I'm getting all values in table as output  `db.collection1.find({"product.structure.version.type.values.name":{$in:[1,'test']}}).pretty()`

Comment: following is my schema  `product: [{ product_name: { type: String, required: true }, 
            structure: [{ structure_name: { type: String, required: true },
                 version: [{version_name: { type: String, required: true },                  type: [{  type_name: { type: String }, values: [{  value1: { type: String }, value2: { type: String },  value3: { type: String }, value4: { type: String },value5: { type: String },  value6: { type: String }, }],}],}],}],}]` and my query is `db.collection1.find({"product.structure.version.type.values.‌​name":{$in:[1,'value1'‌​]}}).pretty()`